# How to import m4v files into iTunes 12.2.1.16 on Mac OS X 10.1.2.16?

Tags: macos, itunes, appletv

I converted some mkv files into AppleTV3 files with Handbrake so I could import them into iTunes to watch on my AppleTV 3.

I can't seem to import these files into iTunes 12.2.1.16  on Mac OS X 10.1.2.16
I've tried dragging the files and using File> "Open File"
No error messages appear.

How do I import m4v files into iTunes?
If this is not possible, what format should the files be converted?

Comment: Excuse me, are you *sure* you mean Mac OS X 10.1.2.16?  You're using *Puma,* an OS from *fifteen years* ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding an .m4v file, or other acceptable A/V type file extensions, to iTunes either by drag and drop or using File > Add to Library... the file is added to Home Videos under Movies.

In a fresh install of OS X, in the image below, it shows the available tabs when selecting Movies in iTunes.  Note there is no Home Videos tab.

[image: iTunes without any videos.]

In the image below, after adding a video to iTunes the Home Videos tab appears under Movies and shows the added video.

[image: iTunes with added video.]

Comment: You are correct. I was doing it correctly, but the name of the file was being changed.

Comment: @BryanWheelock, Not sure what you mean by "_but the name of the file was being changed_" however it's not changing in mine unless I delete it while opting to keep the file and then add it again.  The name is  then incremented by 1 each time.